# IE flexible box model not working

Tags: css, flexbox

Im trying to implement the flexible box model into my website, and while its working for the -webkit-browsers like chrome and safari, other browsers like mozilla and opera, I jus cant seem to get it working in Internet Explorer, no matter what I do. Heres a short snippet of my Css stylesheet file containing my .holder class which houses everything, and my #new_div id which is a child of .holder and houses my main section for posts and sidebar.

```
.holder
{
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-o-box;
    display:-ms-box;
    display:-box;
    display:-pie;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -moz-box-orient:vertical;
    -o-box-orient:vertical;
    -ms-box-orient:vertical;
    -box-orient:vertical;
    -pie-box-orient:vertical;
    -moz-box-flex:1;    /* Firefox, seamonkey etc */
    -o-box-flex:1;      /* Opera */
    -ms-box-flex:1;     /* MSIE */
    -box-flex:1;         /* Any that support full implementation */
    -pie-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -o-box-pack:center;
    -ms-box-pack:center;
    -pie-box-pack:center;
    -box-pack:center; 
    text-align:center;
    behavior: url(../../Content/pie/PIE.htc);
}

.holder #new_div
{
    width:940px;
}
.holder div
{
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -o-box-pack:center;
    -ms-box-pack:center;
    -box-pack:center; 
    -pie-box-pack:center;
    behavior: url(../../Content/pie/PIE.htc);
}
#new_div
{
    margin:auto;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-o-box;
    display:-ms-box;
    display:-box;
    display:-pie-box;
    text-align:left;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -moz-box-flex:1;    /* Firefox, seamonkey etc */
    -o-box-flex:1;      /* Opera */
    -ms-box-flex:1;     /* MSIE */ 
    -box-flex:1; 
    -pie-box:1;     
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -box-pack:center;
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    -o-box-pack:center;
    -ms-box-pack:center; 
    -pie-box-pack:center;
    background-color:#25282D;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    -o-box-orient:horizontal;
    -ms-box-orient:horizontal;
    -box-orient:horizontal;
    -pie-box-orient:horizontal;
    min-width:940px; 
    padding:20px;
    behavior: url(../../Content/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

There you can see I have the -ms-box-.. names defined along side the other definitions, however it still doesnt seem to register. I've tried using the CSS3Pie library out of desperation though that didnt work, tryed installing the Chrome plugin for IE though that failed also and I'm jus out of ideas on what to do guys. Maybe there could be a syntax problem with the css I already have written thats throwhing it off, but as I said it works fine in the others browsers. Any suggestions or tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS flexbox not working in IE10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019450/css-flexbox-not-working-in-ie10)

Comment: Flexbox browser support: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE doesn't use the [deprecated 2009 Flexbox properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/), it uses the ones from the deprecated [March 2012 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/).  Opera supports the [Flexbox standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/) properties without prefixes and the 2009 properties under the -webkit- prefix.

```
.holder {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.holder #new_div {
  width: 940px;
}

.holder div {
  /* justify-content does nothing here since this element isn't a flex container */
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#new_div {
  margin: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* this shouldn't be necessary, as the default direction is `row` */
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-width: 940px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Also worth noting, this requires IE10+

Comment: Just to get this straight here, justify-content:column was added apart of the March 2012 release along with flex direction? And with the -webkit- and -moz- prefixes of orient:horizontal, thats not needed anymore and is replaced with column? Sorry for the premature responsive questions, I'm still a  new to the css3 stream of things.

Comment: What properties you need depends on which browsers you want to target.  Firefox hasn't transitioned over to using the standard properties yet, its still stuck on 2009.  Same goes for Safari and every mobile webkit browser except for Blackberry 10.  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Comment: Thanks bro!!! Appreciate the assistance and support, I would hvae never known of this!