# CSS flexbox not working in IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

In IE10, this code isn't working correctly:

```
.flexbox form {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -o-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexbox form input[type=submit] {
    width: 31px;
}

.flexbox form input[type=text] {
    width: auto;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: auto 1;
    -moz-flex: auto 1;
    -ms-flex: auto 1;
    -o-flex: auto 1;
    flex: auto 1;
}
```

What should happen is that `input[type=submit]` should be 31px wide, with `input[type=text]` taking up the rest of the available space within `form`. What happens is `input[type=text]` just defaults to 263px for some reason.

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE flexible box model not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487884/ie-flexible-box-model-not-working)

Comment: Don't just apply randomly apply prefixes, it doesn't work due to the multiple Flexbox draft implementations:  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Comment: Flexbox browser support: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: Please note that flex items should be display:block; in IE10.

Comment: Use autoprefixer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Flex layout modes are not (fully) natively supported in IE yet.  IE10 implements the "tween" version of the spec which is not fully recent, but still works.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

This CSS-Tricks article has some advice on cross-browser use of flexbox (including IE):
http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

edit: after a bit more research, IE10 flexbox layout mode implemented current to the March 2012 W3C draft spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/

The most current draft is a year or so more recent: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/

Comment: An older version is supported in IE10, take a look at note [1] in the link you posted.

Comment: Yes, there are some `-ms-` prefixed flexbox vendor properties, but as I understand they are based on an outdated version of the CSS3 flexbox specification (unless that MDN info is just outdated, which is possible).

Comment: I don't care if it's an older spec, if it works, at least partially, then that's fine. I'm trying to adapt stuff from the CSS Tricks article you posted, will report back if it fixes it.

Comment: I was able to use the CSS tricks article you linked to to get this working, and actually I understand a bit more about what was wrong with my code now.

Comment: Surely it won't be much longer before Microsoft drops IE10 support altogether... I wonder how many of our clients use Windows Server 2012... https://www.xfive.co/blog/stop-supporting-ie10-ie9-ie8/

Comment: I used styles exactly as they are written in CSS-Tricks article and they did not work on IE 10

Answer (score 39):

As Ennui mentioned, IE 10 supports the `-ms` prefixed version of Flexbox (IE 11 supports it unprefixed).  The errors I can see in your code are:

- You should have `display: -ms-flexbox` instead of `display: -ms-flex`
- I think you should specify all 3 `flex` values, like `flex: 0 1 auto` to avoid ambiguity

So the final updated code is...

```
.flexbox form {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;

    /* Direction defaults to 'row', so not really necessary to specify */
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -o-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flexbox form input[type=submit] {
    width: 31px;
}

.flexbox form input[type=text] {
    width: auto;

    /* Flex should have 3 values which is shorthand for 
       <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis> */
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -moz-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -o-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;

    /* I don't think you need 'display: flex' on child elements * /
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    /**/
}
```

Comment: Correct - you **don't** need display: flex on children (`<input>`).  It's **display: flex** on the containing element – to switch flexbox on – and **flex: …** on the children to specify the size etc.

Answer (score 11):

IE10 has uses the old syntax. So:

```
display: -ms-flexbox; /* will work on IE10 */
display: flex; /* is new syntax, will not work on IE10 */
```

see [css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

> (tweener) means an odd unofficial syntax from [2012] (e.g. display: flexbox;)

Comment: ('first post' comment)  link only answers are discouraged (because the link targets can disappear). It's fine to add links but a little bit of information (ideally enough to answer the question) is better practise. Thanks!.