# Flexbox not working on IE10

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend, internet-explorer-10

Hi the following code works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but I cannot make it work in IE. I have tried `display: -ms-flexbox`, but it does not help.

Html:

```
<div class="contener">
  <span class="editableLabel">
    <span class="contentTrimmed">aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh iiii jjjj kkkk llll mmmm nnnn</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contener {
  width: 300px;
}

.editableLabel {
    display: flex;
}

.contentTrimmed {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73ajt17v/2/)

The result I want to obtain is the trimmed text if it is longer than 300px.

Comment: its supported in IE 11 and above, check here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Any idea how to obtain that behaviour in IE 8-10?

Comment: as per your requirement you can achieve it using display:block, why flex, any specific reason?

Comment: question already answered check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019450/css-flexbox-not-working-in-ie10?rq=1

Comment: @SanjeevK no specific reason. Do you mean just replace `display: flex;` with `display: block;`? I am afraid it also does not work :(

Comment: I don't have IE 10, but its working fine in IE11 and it should work in IE 10 as well.

Comment: @Khurram Unfortunately, I didn't find an answear to my question there.

Comment: @SanjeevK yes, in IE11 everything is ok, but IE10 does not trim the text.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.contener {
  width: 300px;
}

.editableLabel {
    display: flex;
}

.contentTrimmed {
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
word-break: break-all;
white-space: normal;


}
```

```html
<div class="contener">
  <span class="editableLabel">
    <span class="contentTrimmed">aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh iiii jjjj kkkk llll mmmm nnnn</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; this code is there ..i have done it crome ,modizilla,IE9,10,11 and  safari,

Comment: are you trying to wrap it or ,,u trying to create a new web browser  the word "-webkit;" itself describes it is for chrome

Comment: your solution breaks the content into the other line but I want to trim it so if it is longer than 300px 3 dots will appear at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .contener {
         width: 300px;
       }  

    .editableLabel {
        display: flex;
   }

     .contentTrimmed {
          display: inline-block;
         text-overflow: ellipsis;
         white-space: nowrap;
         overflow: hidden;
          max-width: 300px;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="contener">
      <span class="editableLabel">
        <span class="contentTrimmed">aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh iiii jjjj kkkk llll mmmm nnnn</span>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: change the max-width value and observe it fine! bro

Comment: add ""display: inline-block"" in the  "".contentTrimmed"" class and check again