# Bootstrap 4 Modal styling (FlexBox) not working in IE

Tags: css, reactjs, internet-explorer, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am creating a confirm dialog using Bootstrap 4 and the code goes like this

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="completeAlertDialogue" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Navigation</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p>You haven't saved your changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page?</p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="order-2"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button></div>
            <div class="mr-auto order-1"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">No</button></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The styling is working fine in chrome, firefox, edge but not working in IE

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome Modal]

**IE11**
[image]

Created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kurx1tqe/) for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019450/css-flexbox-not-working-in-ie10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following HTML structure for "`modal-footer`"

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="modal fade show" id="completeAlertDialogue" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Navigation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You haven't saved your changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-start">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <button class="ml-auto btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure why are you keeping the Yes/No divs in opposite order in HTML when you want to paint them other way round. So I have changed their position in HTML. So you wont require order-* property now.

Answer (score 1):

display flex is not full support in IE.
i change footer display `flex` to `block`, then its work. check bellow code

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="completeAlertDialogue" role="dialog" style="display: block;">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Navigation</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p>You haven't saved your changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page?</p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer d-block">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-6"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button></div>
               <div class="col-sm-6 text-right"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">No</button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```