# Input field sneaks into a div with labels in IE 11

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

CSS:

```
.container {
    margin-right: 75px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.input-large {
    width: 210px;
}
.label-a {
    float: left;
}
.label-b {
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <label class="label-a">label-a</label>
        <label class="label-b">label-b</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input-large" type="text" />
</div>
```

[Result in IE 11 and Chrome (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvVAq.png)

Why the input field is placed between two labels in IE 11, but in Chrome it is fine?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
    margin-right: 75px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width:215px;
}
.input-large {
    width: 210px;
}
.lablerow{float:left;width:100%;}
.label-a {
    float: left;
}
.label-b {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="lablerow">
        <label class="label-a">label-a</label>
        <label class="label-b">label-b</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input-large" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, thanks, that will work. I was able to do it via flexbox, I just wonder why it happens in IE.

Comment: Can you refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019450/css-flexbox-not-working-in-ie10

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of flexbox compatibility on IE, but simple justify-content space between works for labels. I'm curious about what actually makes that example display wrong in IE and correctly in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the input element varies across the browsers. I have confirmed this by inspecting the elements in the browser. I believe IE might also view `width` differently to chrome eg. width of the content or width of the content and padding.

(Also if you are planning on using flex boxes I recommend also taking a look at CSS grid as an alternative because it works in 2D not just down the page).

Answer (score 0):

This seems due to IE and Chrome takes different widths of the container `div`.

In IE, the width of the container `div` is the sum width of `input`, `label-a` and `label-b`:

[image]

But in Chrome, the width of the container `div` takes the width of `input`:

[image]

As IE and Chrome have different rendering engines, they have different ways to calculate the element width. If we want the same display in IE, we need to set a width to the container.